# Does this have a name?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

While messing around, I seem to have stumbled upon an interesting family of matrices:

$$\mathbb{S} = \bigg\lbrace A\in\mathbb{M}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{R}) : A^{T}A=AA^{T}=\frac{1}{2} (A + A^{T})\bigg\rbrace$$

In searching for matrices that belong to this set, I've noticed that for any orthogonal matrix $Q$, $\frac{1}{2}(I_n - Q)\in\mathbb{S}$, where $I_n$ is the $n\times n$ identity matrix.

Also, any $A\in\mathbb{S}$ is positive semi-definite, since:

$$\vec{x}^{T}A\vec{x} = \vec{x}^{T} \left( \frac{1}{2} (A + A^{T}) \right)\vec{x} = \vec{x}^{T}A^{T}A\vec{x} = \| A\vec{x}\|^{2} \geq 0$$

I've also noticed that it's not a vector space, nor is it closed under matrix multiplication. But does $\mathbb{S}$, or relationships like it have a name?

edit: fixed typo pointed out by user1551

Comment: A real matrix satisfying $A^TA=AA^T$ is called *normal*, so $\mathcal{S}$ is a subset of normal matrices.

Comment: Yes; this means that $A$ is orthogonally diagonalizable as well. Does the product $A^{T} A$ or $A A^{T}$ have a name?

Comment: The set $\mathbb S$ contains precisely those matrices of the form $A=\frac12(I-Q)$ (rather than $2(I-Q)$), where $Q$ is real orthogonal. Note that $A$ is not always symmetric, and hence it is *not* regarded as positive semidefinite in the usual definition.

Comment: Oh good call! The $\frac{1}{2}$ was a typo on my part. I guess I could be a little more rigorous and say that the symmetric part of $A$ is positive semi-definite. You also mention that the set $\mathbb{S}$ contains precisely the matrices of the form $A = \frac{1}{2}(I-Q)$ for a real orthogonal matrix $Q$; do you have a proof of this? Obviously for any orthogonal $Q$ there is an $A\in\mathbb{S}$, but I'm not sure how to go the other way. Thanks!

Comment: Try letting $A=\frac12(I-B)$ and proving that $B$ is orthogonal.

Comment: Right, got it! Thanks!